# Coordinating and subordinating conjunctions

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

I'm having several problems with syntax analysis.
Is it possible to have **4 subordinating and 1 coordinating conjunction together in 1 sentence?** How do I analyze clauses like that?

*This is the sentence with which I have problems:* *Is a compound-complex sentence?*

> When Jill said that she would be available tomorrow, she did not know that the time had been changed and that she would not be back before the children had come home.

Comment: The sentence looks fine to me. What "problems" are you having with it exactly? As currently written I think this question is too vague to answer.

Comment: Thank you, and I'm sorry if the question is unclear, it is really difficult for me to even explain the difficulties I am going through.

Comment: What do you consider to be the subordinators?

Comment: Does it help to see that it is of the form _When X, she did not know A and B_? If your definition of compound complex depends on the number of independent clauses then you should be able to see the answer.